# I am not able to query in elastic search with out properties.<fieldname>

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-mapping

This is the query that is used for searching :

```
{ "query": {
  "term": {"properties.subscriptionid": "test"
  }
    }
   }
```

Result :

```
  
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "ILojbHQB1164tHwpvfoc",
                "_source": {
                    "properties": {
                        "subscriptionid": "test",
                    }
```

If i use :

```
{ "query": {
    "term": {"subscriptionid": "test"
    }
      }
     }
```

I am not getting any result.

Index mappings :

```
  "mappings": {
       "properties": {
         "subscriptionid": {
            "type": "keyword"
         },
         "resources":{
            "type": "nested",
}
}
```

*Removed not necessary to decrease the code area

Comment: I'm pretty sure your effective mapping is not the same as the one you think you have installed. Can you show what you get when running `GET your-index` and update your question with the results?

Comment: yeah when inserting the _doc the index got changed, Thanks for it bro!!!

Comment: Yes, because the document you index contains the `properties` hash, which it should not according to your mapping, just remove that part and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As @Val pointed out, there is some mismatch in the index mapping that you have posted in the question. Refer [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html), to get a detailed insight on it.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping(same as mentioned in the question) and search query.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "resources": {
        "type": "nested" 
      },
      "subscriptionid": {
        "type": "keyword" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "subscriptionid": "test",
  "resources": [
    {
      "title": "elasticsearch"
    }
  ]
}

{
   "subscriptionid": "test"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "subscriptionid": "test"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "subscriptionid": "test"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Search Query for nested type with term query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "resources",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "term": { "resources.title": "elasticsearch" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result for nested mapping:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "subscriptionid": "test",
          "resources": [
            {
              "title": "elasticsearch"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Panther_11 did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from u :)